# Swift -Converted Audio URL to Video URL Doesn't Play in Photos Library

Tags: ios, swift, url, uiactivityviewcontroller

I have an audio url (.m4a) that I create using the AVAudioRecorder. I want to share that audio on Instagram so I convert the audio to a video. The issue is after the conversion, when I save the video url to the Files app using the UIActivityViewController, I can replay the video, see the time (eg 7 seconds) and hear the audio with no problem. A black screen with a sound icon appears.

But when I save the video to the Photos Library using the UIActivityViewController, the video shows the 7 seconds but nothing plays, the video is all gray, and the sound icon doesn't show.

Why is the video successfully saving/playing in the Files app but saving and not playing in the Photos Library?

```
let asset: AVURLAsset = AVURLAsset(url: audioURL)

let mixComposition = AVMutableComposition()
guard let compositionTrack = mixComposition.addMutableTrack(withMediaType: .audio, preferredTrackID: CMPersistentTrackID()) else { return }

let track = asset.tracks(withMediaType: .audio)
guard let assetTrack = track.first else { return }

do {
            
    try compositionTrack.insertTimeRange(CMTimeRangeMake(start: .zero, duration: assetTrack.timeRange.duration), of: assetTrack, at: .zero)
            
} catch {
    print(error.localizedDescription)
}

guard let exporter = AVAssetExportSession(asset: mixComposition, presetName: AVAssetExportPresetPassthrough) else { return }

let dirPath = NSTemporaryDirectory().appending("\(UUID().uuidString).mov")
let outputFileURL = URL(fileURLWithPath: dirPath)

exporter.outputFileType = .mov
exporter.outputURL = outputFileURL
exporter.shouldOptimizeForNetworkUse = true

exporter.exportAsynchronously {
    switch exporter.status {

    // ...
    guard let videoURL = exporter.outputURL else { return }


        // present UIActivityViewController to save videoURL and then save it to the Photos Library via 'Save Video`
    }
}
```

Comment: Any difference if you change the output file type from `.mov` to `.mp4` ?

Comment: I haven't tried. Let me see what happen now. Gimme a few

Comment: @ShawnFrank thanks for the help but the same exact issue occurred. Strange problem

Comment: Let me try something at my end, just to confirm, end result is to convert an mp3 into a video file so that the audio plays but the visual can just be black. Should play in photos app as a video and also sharable as a video ?

Comment: @ShawnFrank the audio file is initially `.m4a`. Yes, convert the audio file to a video file using mixComposition. Then the resulting video is a video with a black visual. It should play in both the Files app and the Photos Library as a video but of course you will only hear sound. Once saved the black video should be shareable from that point on

Comment: @ShawnFrank when using the `UIActivityViewController`, you're going to see multiple options, specifically `Save to Files` (Files app) and `Save Video` (Photos Library)

Comment: @ShawnFrank I found the problem. Please read the answer below. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Lance rightfully pointed out, the issue is that while there was an export of a file in the `.mov` or `.mp4` format, there was no video, it was just an audio playing.

On reading a bit more, .mp4 for example is just a digital multimedia container format which can very well just be used for audio so it's possible to save audio file as a .mp4 / .mov.

What was needed was to add an empty video track to the `AVMutableComposition` to succeed. Lance already posted a great solution works perfectly well and is more `self sustained` than an alternative solution I propose which relies on having a blank 1 second video.

**Overview of how it works**

1. You get a blank video file that is 1 second long in the resolution you want, for example 1920 x 1080
2. You retrieve the video track from this video asset
3. Retrieve the audio track from your audio file
4. Create an `AVMutableComposition` which will be used to merge the audio and video tracks
5. Configure an `AVMutableCompositionTrack` with the audio track and add that to the main `AVMutableComposition`
6. Configure an `AVMutableVideoComposition` with the video track
7. Use an `AVAssetExportSession` to export the final video with the `AVMutableComposition` and the `AVMutableVideoComposition`

**The code**

In most of the code below you will see multiple guard statements. You can create one guard, however, it can be useful to know with such types of tasks where the failure occurred as there could be several reason why an export could fail.

Configuring the audio track

```
private func configureAudioTrack(_ audioURL: URL,
                                 inComposition composition: AVMutableComposition) -> AVMutableCompositionTrack?
{
    // Initialize an AVURLAsset with your audio file
    let audioAsset: AVURLAsset = AVURLAsset(url: audioURL)
    
    let trackTimeRange = CMTimeRange(start: .zero,
                                     duration: audioAsset.duration)
    
    // Get the audio track from the audio asset
    guard let sourceAudioTrack = audioAsset.tracks(withMediaType: .audio).first
    else
    {
        manageError(nil, withMessage: "Error retrieving audio track from source file")
        return nil
    }
    
    // Insert a new video track to the AVMutableComposition
    guard let audioTrack = composition.addMutableTrack(withMediaType: .audio,
                                                       preferredTrackID: CMPersistentTrackID())
    else
    {
        // manage your error
        return nil
    }
    
    do {
        // Inset the contents of the audio source into the new audio track
        try audioTrack.insertTimeRange(trackTimeRange,
                                       of: sourceAudioTrack,
                                       at: .zero)
    }
    catch {
        // manage your error
    }
    
    return audioTrack
}
```

Configuring the video track

```
private func configureVideoTrack(inComposition composition: AVMutableComposition) -> AVMutableCompositionTrack?
{
    // Initialize a video asset with the empty video file
    guard let blankMoviePathURL = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "blank",
                                                  withExtension: ".mp4"), 
    let videoAsset = AVAsset(url: blankMoviePathURL)
    else
    {
        // manage errors
        return nil
    }
    
    // Get the video track from the empty video
    guard let sourceVideoTrack = videoAsset.tracks(withMediaType: .video).first
    else
    {
        // manage errors
        return nil
    }
    
    // Insert a new video track to the AVMutableComposition
    guard let videoTrack = composition.addMutableTrack(withMediaType: .video,
                                                       preferredTrackID: kCMPersistentTrackID_Invalid)
    else
    {
        // manage errors
        return nil
    }
    
    let trackTimeRange = CMTimeRange(start: .zero,
                                     duration: composition.duration)
    
    do {
        
        // Inset the contents of the video source into the new audio track
        try videoTrack.insertTimeRange(trackTimeRange,
                                       of: sourceVideoTrack,
                                       at: .zero)
        
    }
    catch {
        // manage errors
    }
    
    return videoTrack
}
```

Configure the video composition

```
// Configure the video properties like resolution and fps
private func createVideoComposition(with videoCompositionTrack: AVMutableCompositionTrack) -> AVMutableVideoComposition
{
    let videoComposition = AVMutableVideoComposition()
    
    // Set the fps
    videoComposition.frameDuration = CMTime(value: 1,
                                            timescale: 25)
    
    // Video dimensions
    videoComposition.renderSize = CGSize(width: 1920, height: 1080)
    
    // Specify the duration of the video composition
    let instruction = AVMutableVideoCompositionInstruction()
    instruction.timeRange = CMTimeRange(start: .zero, duration: .indefinite)
    
    // Add the video composition track to a new layer
    let layerInstruction = AVMutableVideoCompositionLayerInstruction(assetTrack: videoCompositionTrack)
    let transform = videoCompositionTrack.preferredTransform
    layerInstruction.setTransform(transform, at: .zero)
    
    // Apply the layer configuration instructions
    instruction.layerInstructions = [layerInstruction]
    videoComposition.instructions = [instruction]
    
    return videoComposition
}
```

Configure the AVAssetExportSession

```
private func configureAVAssetExportSession(with composition: AVMutableComposition,
                                           videoComposition: AVMutableVideoComposition) -> AVAssetExportSession?
{
    // Configure export session
    guard let exporter = AVAssetExportSession(asset: composition,
                                              presetName: AVAssetExportPresetHighestQuality)
    else
    {
        // Manage your errors
        return nil
    }
    
    // Configure where the exported file will be stored
    let documentsURL = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory,
                                                in: .userDomainMask)[0]
    
    let fileName = "\(UUID().uuidString).mov"
    let dirPath = documentsURL.appendingPathComponent(fileName)
    let outputFileURL = dirPath
    
    // Apply exporter settings
    exporter.videoComposition = videoComposition
    exporter.outputFileType = .mov
    exporter.outputURL = outputFileURL
    exporter.shouldOptimizeForNetworkUse = true
    
    return exporter
}
```

Over here, one important thing to not is to set the exporter's `present quality` to a movie present like `AVAssetExportPresetHighestQuality` or `AVAssetExportPresetLowQuality` for example, something other than `AVAssetExportPresetPassthrough` which as per the documentation,

> A preset to export the asset in its current format, unless otherwise
> prohibited.

So you would still get an audio mp4 or mov file since the current format of the composition is of an audio. I did not test this extensively but this is from a few tests.

Finally, you can bring it all the above functions together like so:

```
func generateMovie(with audioURL: URL)
{
    delegate?.audioMovieExporterDidStart(self)
    
    let composition = AVMutableComposition()
    
    // Configure the audio and video tracks in the new composition
    guard let _ = configureAudioTrack(audioURL, inComposition: composition),
          let videoCompositionTrack = configureVideoTrack(inComposition: composition)
    else
    {
        // manage error
        return
    }
    
    let videoComposition = createVideoComposition(with: videoCompositionTrack)
    
    if let exporter = configureAVAssetExportSession(with: composition,
                                                    videoComposition: videoComposition)
    {
        exporter.exportAsynchronously
        {
            switch exporter.status {
                
                case .completed:
                    guard let videoURL = exporter.outputURL
                    else
                    {
                        // manage errors
                        return
                    }
                    
                    // notify someone the video is ready at videoURL
                    
                default:
                    // manege error
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Final Thoughts**

1. You could test drive a working sample [here](https://github.com/shawn-frank/AudioMovieExporter)
2. I converted this into a simple library if you wish to use it where you can configure the orientation, fps and even set a background color to the video - available at the [same link](https://github.com/shawn-frank/AudioMovieExporter)
3. If you just want the blank videos, you can get them from [here](https://github.com/shawn-frank/AudioMovieExporter/tree/production/AudioExportExample/AudioExportExample/Libraries/AudioMovieExporter/Media)

Comment: I choose yours as the accepted answer because you have all of the code laid out with everything that someone needs to get started. With my code they have to dig through 2-3 different answers -it’s way more work. Thanks for the help and Happy Coding. Cheers!!!

Answer (score 2):

So it seems that although the code from my question did covert the audio file to a video file, there still wasn't a `video track`. I know this for a fact because after I got the exporter's videoURL from my question, I tried to add a [watermark](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58884279/4833705) to it and in the watermark code it kept crashing on

```
let videoTrack = asset.tracks(withMediaType: AVMediaType.video)[0]
```

**Basically the code from my question coverts audio to video but doesn't add a video track.**

What I assume is happening is when the **Files app** reads the file, it knows that it's a .mov or .mp4 file and then **it'll play the audio track even if the video track is missing**.

Conversely, when the **Photos app** reads the file it also know's that it's a .mov or .mp4 file but **if there isn't a video track, it won't play anything**.

I had to combine these 2 answers to get the audio to play as a video in the Photos app.

**1st-** I added my app icon (you can add any image) as 1 image to an array of images to make a video track using the code from [How do I export UIImage array as a movie?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36290742/4833705) answered by @scootermg.

The code from @scootermg's answer is conveniently in 1 file at this [GitHub](https://github.com/dldnh/make-movie/blob/main/make-movie.swift) by @dldnh. In his code, in the `ImageAnimator` class, in the `render` function, instead of saving to the Library I returned the `videoWriter's output URL` in the completionHandler.

**2nd-** I combined the app icon video that I just made with the audio url from my question using the code from [Swift Merge audio and video files into one video](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48978962/4833705) answered by @TungFam

In the mixCompostion from TungFam's answer I used the audio url's asset duration for the length of the video.

```
do {
    try mutableCompositionVideoTrack[0].insertTimeRange(CMTimeRangeMake(start: .zero,
                                                                            duration: aAudioAssetTrack.timeRange.duration),
                                                            of: aVideoAssetTrack,
                                                            at: .zero)

    try mutableCompositionAudioTrack[0].insertTimeRange(CMTimeRangeMake(start: .zero,
                                                                            duration: aAudioAssetTrack.timeRange.duration),
                                                            of: aAudioAssetTrack,
                                                            at: .zero)

    if let aAudioOfVideoAssetTrack = aAudioOfVideoAssetTrack {
        try mutableCompositionAudioOfVideoTrack[0].insertTimeRange(CMTimeRangeMake(start: .zero,
                                                                                       duration: aAudioAssetTrack.timeRange.duration),
                                                                       of: aAudioOfVideoAssetTrack,
                                                                       at: .zero)
    }
} catch {
    print(error.localizedDescription)
}
```

Comment: nicely done! So it seems you cannot just add a video track, you have to create a blank video. I actually took an easier route which was adding a blank video to my bundle and then work from there. I will post that as an alternative.

Comment: @ShawnFrank thanks . I do the same thing with a blank audio track but for a different reason. Read the **1st comment** under this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/64733623/4833705. I was thinking about adding a blank video track but I wasn’t sure if it was going to continuously loop. For example the blank vid track is 10 seconds but the audio track is 1 minute -would the video track loop 6 times? I have no idea, but if it does I thought maybe it would be annoying. I guess it also depends on what’s on the blank video track. Please post and describe your solution. I would like to see it!